# jQuery click on div that is on top of another div

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with jQuery `click` when the selector is a for a `div` that is on top of another `div` as seen here..

the html

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id="child">
 </div>
</div>​
```

css

```
#parent{
 background-color:red;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;   
 position:relative;
}


#parent:hover #child {
 display:block;

}
#child{
 background-color:yellow;  
 width:10px;
 height:10px;  
 border: 1px solid black;
 position:absolute;
 display:none;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
}
```

js

```
$("#parent").bind("click", function() {
    alert('you clicked on red');
});

$("#child").bind("click", function() {
    alert('you click on yellow');
});​
```

If you click on red `#parent` it gives the proper alert. If you click on yellow `#child`, it gives the yellow alert plus the red alert.

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qTdkt/3/)

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Use jQuery's `.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$("#parent").bind("click", function() {
  alert('you clicked on red');
});

$("#child").bind("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('you click on yellow');  
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qTdkt/4/