# Recognize click on a div which is on the top of another div in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image which is embedded in a div. On the top of the image, I have a fontawsome Icon. When I click on the icon, a list of options opens. These options are basically simple words in divs. I want to print "Hi" when I click on any of these words. I am doing this right now:

```
$(".label").bind("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Hi');

});
```

The event does not get triggered right now.

I looked at the question posted by someone else [jQuery click on div that is on top of another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790673/jquery-click-on-div-that-is-on-top-of-another-div), I tried to use `e.stopPropagation()`, but this also does not work.

Here is my code
https://jsfiddle.net/06mqh3gs/5/

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are creating your Dom elements from the JS side. All you need to do is just add the event listener inside the loop. xD...

```
 function loadKeywords(){
          for(i=0;i<keyword.length;i++){
            $('<div/>', {
                class:"label",
                id:"label_"+i,
                height: "15",
                html:keyword[i]
            }).appendTo(".form");
               $("#label_"+i).bind("click", function(e) {
              e.stopPropagation();
              alert(i);

            });
          }
       }
```

Comment: Really? You are going to bind an event for each label element inside the loop instead of using jQuery functionality to do the same thing with less code?

Comment: @JavaEvgen the question does not ask what is the best approach of implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/06mqh3gs/6/) so it's now working.

Here is your fixed event binder:

```
$(".profile-img-container").on('click', '.label', function() {
   alert("lalala");
});
```

You must use this construction to bind an event listener to dynamicly added element and the static container that is always present on page must be provided

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17605509/4760460) is very helpful.

> To capture events on elements which are created AFTER declaring your event listeners - you should bind to a parent element, or element higher in the hierarchy.

Instead of:

```
$(".label").bind("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('Hi');
});
```

try:

```
$(document).on("click", ".label", function(e) {
  console.log('Hi');
});
```

Comment: That answer you have mentioned does really clear up things related to the question. But the accepted answer is just a trash in my opinion...

Comment: Not trash if the OP wants different click functions for each `.label` but definitely way less efficient if the OP wants the same click function for each `.label`.

Comment: Well you are right, but it says "I want to print "Hi" when I click on any of these words."